# SQL Queries In Python Where Value May Be None/Null

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm writing a Python script to analyse some data, that is sourced from several different SQL databases. Queries to the databases are based on the results of previous queries, to different databases.

The problem that I'm having is that some queries may return `NULL`.

So, if I have a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE fieldA = ?
AND fieldB = ?
```

And I have two values that have been returned from other queries; `field_a = 'A'` and `field_b = None`, when I try to execute the query in Python:

```
with pyodbc.connect('Trusted_connection=yes', driver='{SQL Server}', server=server_name, database=database_name, autocommit=True) as connection:
    ds = connection.execute(sql,[field_a, field_b])
```

nothing is returned. If I change the SQL query so that the None/Null value is hard-coded:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE field_a = ?
AND field_b IS NULL
```

I get the data that I expect.

Is there a better way to deal with this problem other than building the SQL query from substrings based on the field values?

Comment: What about using `AND field_b IS ?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using OR

```
    SELECT *
    FROM table_name
    WHERE (field_a = ? AND field b IS NULL)
    OR (field_a IS NULL AND field b  = ?)
    OR (field_a = ? AND field b  = ?)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The only problem with this is that if you DO get a value from the parameter, you'd want it to only equate to those rows, and in this case you'd get the equating rows, plus all the nulls.

Comment: Thanks and you re right. I edited to get results for Values and in case of nulls for either.

Comment: Thanks, I was making this problem more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `none` gets translated to `null` when it's compiled into SQL. Since a null can never equal anything (not even another null) you'll have to use `is null` like you did when you hard coded the value. What if you want to be able to do both? The route I'd go would be to control for the possibility of a null with something like this:

```
and field_b = isnull(?, '')
```

Of course this has the loophole that if field_b actually IS an empty string, it will equate when you don't intend it to. Depending on whether that's a problem or not, you could also get creative with `case` statements or `or` conditions.